# TimeoutException in SQL Server 2005 migrated from SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, timeout, database-migration

I've recently updated an MSSQL server from 2000 version to 2005, to make use of UDFs and tweak some results in a system. The thing is that we don't have the source code.

So, I replaced the SQL version, and every worked fine... except when we have to do a large query. I'm getting this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

I've searched about it, and what I get is that it use to be a `CommandTimeout` issue that I have to solve programmatically, as it is supposed to be in the client side, but this is weird, because it always worked even with big queries.

My guess is that is not something Client Side because in SQL Server 2000 worked fine.

Is there any way to remove any kind of timeout? The system is completely internal and only a few people uses it, so there's no risk of outages... I prefer a query running forever that this annoying messages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you've made use of UDFs and "tweaked" the server side code, beyond changing database versions. Have you tried rolling back your fixes in an attempt to isolate whether it's a version issue or your "tweaks?"

Comment: The timeout is set by the client not SQL Server so you can't alter it from the SQL Server end.

Comment: @Martin ok, get it, but why it worked in 2000 if it is in the client side? Thanks!

Comment: @Gonzalo- Some of your queries must be taking longer now.

Comment: @Martin nope, they don't. I've checked it out. We never received a Timeout error before, even with longer queries.

Comment: If you set the database compatibility back to 2000 mode, what happens?

Comment: Didn't noticed that exists a compatibility mode. Let me try!

Comment: @bilinkc nope, changed it to 80 and restarted the db engine (just in case), but timeout is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the timeout on the connection either in your config file or at time of setting connection.

SqlCommand1.CommandTimeout = 400000

Comment: The thing is that we don't have the source code. :-/ But, there's not any setting in the client side, because when it connected to the sql server 2000, it actually worked. There's no way to set the default value in the server?

Comment: @Gonzalo - if you can't control the Client's CommandTimeout value, then i'd suggest profiling the sql calls the app is making and query tuning them to alleviate the problem.

Comment: I can't remember off top of head for SQL 2005 but in 2008 you can right click on server in Management studio, go to Properties and then down to connections and set the remote query timeout.

Comment: Finally I decompiled the DLL and added this after SQLCommand creation:
    ldloc.0
    ldc.i4.s    0
    callvirt    instance void [System.Data]System.Data.IDbCommand::set_CommandTimeout(int32)

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated all statistics after the upgrade?

[How to: Upgrade to SQL Server 2005 (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

> After upgrading the Database Engine to SQL Server 2005, complete the
>   following tasks:
>
> ...
>
> **Update statistics** - To help optimize query performance, we recommend
>   that you update statistics on all databases following upgrade. Use the
>   sp_updatestats stored procedure to update statistics in user-defined
>   tables in SQL Server 2005 databases.
>
> **Update usage counters** - In earlier versions of SQL Server, the values
>   for the table and index row counts and page counts can become
>   incorrect. To correct any invalid row or page counts, we recommend
>   that you run DBCC UPDATEUSAGE on all databases following upgrade.

Comment: Yep, I did it. Anyway, the issue is not how time the query takes. I need to be able to run long queries as I did in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @Gonzalo - Just thought i'd ask since bad statistics could definitely cause the sudden timeouts you're experiencing since the upgrade.